# How to prove this determinant equation?

Tags: matrices, summation, determinant

Given two matrices $A \in \text{Mat}_{n\times m}$ and $B \in \text{Mat}_{m\times n}$ for $m \geq n$, I need to prove this:

$$\det(AB) = \sum\limits_I \det(A_I)\det(B_I),$$

where I passes (?) all n-element subsets of $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ and $A_I$ means $n\times n$ matrix that has columns with numbers from $I$, and $B_I$ means the same, but for rows.

Comment: What's your definition for the determinant?

Comment: You generate an $n\times n$ matrix from the row/column indices indicated by the set $I$ I think is what is meant here.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Yup, that's probably it. English's not my native tongue, so...

Comment: @Nameless The usual one, I guess? Are there different definitions?

Comment: It's the *Cauchy-Binet* formula. For a proof, see, e.g., [here](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_11/CauchyBinet1.pdf).